# Group data by first char in JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

I want to group JSON by First char of first name but the resultant object should have two attributes "Key" & "Data"

I tried using lodash which has given me partial expected result but not the complete.

Following are the details with data, expected result, current result and current code implemented using lodash.

Any help will be appreciated.

**JSON:**

```
UserData = [  
        {  
         "gender":"male",
         "name":{
            "title":"mr",
            "first":"landon",
            "last":"gonzalez",
        },
         "location":{  
            "street":"7927 bollinger rd",
            "city":"madison",
            "state":"washington",
            "postcode":24642
         },
         "email":"landon.gonzalez@example.com",
         "dob":"1972-04-26 11:40:09",
         "registered":"2013-07-04 17:42:44",
         "phone":"(038)-931-4026",
         "cell":"(808)-824-5320",
         "nat":"US"
        },
        {  
         "gender":"male",
            "title":"mr",
            "first_name":"jonathan",
            "last_name":"petersen",
         "location":{  
            "street":"2583 brorsonsvej",
            "city":"brøndby strand",
            "state":"hovedstaden",
            "postcode":87814
         },
         "email":"jonathan.petersen@example.com",
         "dob":"1948-05-06 21:48:27",
         "registered":"2009-03-09 17:04:40",
         "phone":"03441612",
         "cell":"73824887",
         "nat":"DK"
      },
        {  
         "gender":"male",
         "name":{
            "title":"mr",
            "first":"roméo",
            "last":"marchand",
            },
         "location":{  
            "street":"9471 rue bony",
            "city":"créteil",
            "state":"maine-et-loire",
            "postcode":30698
         },
         "email":"roméo.marchand@example.com",
         "dob":"1969-08-18 16:41:01",
         "registered":"2015-04-21 19:26:04",
         "phone":"04-43-18-74-25",
         "cell":"06-83-89-77-72",
         "nat":"FR"
      }
    ]
```

**Expected:**

```
[
{ key: 'A', data: [{...}, {...}, {...}] },
{ key: 'B', data: [{...}, {...}, {...}] },
{ key: 'C', data: [{...}, {...}, {...}] },
]
```

**Current:**

```
[
{ 'A': [{...}, {...}, {...}] },
{ 'B': [{...}, {...}, {...}] },
{ 'C': [{...}, {...}, {...}] },
]
```

**Current Code:**

```
  sectionListData(users){
   let sectionedUsers = _.groupBy(users, function(user) {
        return user.first_name.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(sectionedUsers));
  }
```

Comment: Why is current result so bad? You can access your groups by: variableName['A'] (for example)

Comment: @NoOorZ24 its is not bad but I have to use it with react-native section list. Which needs to have the specific format.

Comment: the second entry does not match the name style of the other entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`lodash.chain`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#chain) and after [`grouping`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy), [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#map) the results to create objects of your choice:

```js
let UserData = [{
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "title": "mr",
      "first": "landon",
      "last": "gonzalez",
    },
    "location": {
      "street": "7927 bollinger rd",
      "city": "madison",
      "state": "washington",
      "postcode": 24642
    },
    "email": "landon.gonzalez@example.com",
    "dob": "1972-04-26 11:40:09",
    "registered": "2013-07-04 17:42:44",
    "phone": "(038)-931-4026",
    "cell": "(808)-824-5320",
    "nat": "US"
  },
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "title": "mr",
    "first_name": "jonathan",
    "last_name": "petersen",
    "location": {
      "street": "2583 brorsonsvej",
      "city": "brøndby strand",
      "state": "hovedstaden",
      "postcode": 87814
    },
    "email": "jonathan.petersen@example.com",
    "dob": "1948-05-06 21:48:27",
    "registered": "2009-03-09 17:04:40",
    "phone": "03441612",
    "cell": "73824887",
    "nat": "DK"
  },
  {
    "gender": "male",
    "name": {
      "title": "mr",
      "first": "roméo",
      "last": "marchand",
    },
    "location": {
      "street": "9471 rue bony",
      "city": "créteil",
      "state": "maine-et-loire",
      "postcode": 30698
    },
    "email": "roméo.marchand@example.com",
    "dob": "1969-08-18 16:41:01",
    "registered": "2015-04-21 19:26:04",
    "phone": "04-43-18-74-25",
    "cell": "06-83-89-77-72",
    "nat": "FR"
  }
];

let sectionedUsers = _.chain(UserData)
  .groupBy(function(user) {
    let firstName = _.get(user, 'name.first') || user.first_name;
    return firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  })
  .map((data, key) => ({
    key,
    data
  }))
  .value();

console.log(sectionedUsers);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why to use chain if it can be done without it like done by @NinaScholz

Comment: @NikhilGupta -- What I've used is called explicit chaining in lodash. Chained values have to be unwrapped using `.value()` in the end. If you observe your browser's console while running @NinaScholz's answer, you will get to know that what's printed is not actually a JS object, but a lodash wrapped object. Read more about chaining [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#lodash).

Comment: great answer, I understood the difference. Do you know if it is possible to sort the initial array or the resultant array by name using lodash?

Comment: @NikhilGupta -- use [`lodash.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#sortBy) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/#map) the grouped result.

```js
var userData = [{ gender: "male", name: { title: "mr", first: "landon", last: "gonzalez" }, location: { street: "7927 bollinger rd", city: "madison", state: "washington", postcode: 24642 }, email: "landon.gonzalez@example.com", dob: "1972-04-26 11:40:09", registered: "2013-07-04 17:42:44", phone: "(038)-931-4026", cell: "(808)-824-5320", nat: "US" }, { gender: "male", title: "mr", name: { first: "jonathan", last: "petersen" }, location: { street: "2583 brorsonsvej", city: "brøndby strand", state: "hovedstaden", postcode: 87814 }, email: "jonathan.petersen@example.com", dob: "1948-05-06 21:48:27", registered: "2009-03-09 17:04:40", phone: "03441612", cell: "73824887", nat: "DK" }, { gender: "male", name: { title: "mr", first: "roméo", last: "marchand" }, location: { street: "9471 rue bony", city: "créteil", state: "maine-et-loire", postcode: 30698 }, email: "roméo.marchand@example.com", dob: "1969-08-18 16:41:01", registered: "2015-04-21 19:26:04", phone: "04-43-18-74-25", cell: "06-83-89-77-72", nat: "FR" }];
 
let sectionedUsers = _(userData)
        .groupBy(user => user.name.first[0].toUpperCase())
        .map((data, key) => ({ key, data }))
        .value(); 

console.log(sectionedUsers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should call `.value()` in the end, so that `sectionedUsers` actually contain the result, and not a lodash wrapper object.